# Happens or Happen

Tags: word-choice

We have a sign on our wall which at first glance I thought nothing about until someone mentioned that it was gramatically bad, it says

"All the exciting things we do with digital data happens in here"

The question is....should the word HAPPENS be happen, happens or can it be either?

Thanks!

Comment: The subject of your sentence is "*things*". It's plural. Things *happen*. Things happens is not grammatical.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the same outcome as we came to :D

Comment: Armen is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a subject contains a plural noun or pronoun, the verb should be singular and vice-versa.

The *boy* **runs** every day = Singular **Subject** + Plural **Verb**

His *friends* **run** every day=Plural **Subject** + Singular **Verb**

Additionally,
When a compound subject contains both a singular and a plural noun or pronoun joined by or or nor, the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer the verb.

The boy or his friends run every day.

His friends or the boy runs every day.